# Great CSV module for python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm automating a long task that involves vulnerabilities within a spreadsheet. However, I'm noticing that the "recommendation" for these vulnerabilities are sometimes pretty long.

The CSV module for python seems to be truncating some of this text when writing new rows. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I simply see "NOTE: THIS FIELD WAS TRUNCATED" in places where the recommendation (which is a lot of text) would be.

Comment: Would you please show some sample code, input and output?

Comment: Is the field being truncated by Python, or by Excel when it reads the CSV file? Are the contents truncated if you open the file in Notepad or so?

Comment: Yep. If I "cat <csv file>" I see the text that says "this field was truncated" as well.

Comment: Can't find anything that would cause that in the CSV writing code. Perhaps it's already truncated when the sheet is being imported into Python?

Comment: Ahhhh!!!! Thank you so much, sir! Apparently when converting XLSX to CSV, it got truncated then.

Comment: Note that if you use the xlrd and xlwt modules, working directly with XLSX is as easy (in my opinion) than working with CSV files. You can say which fields are numbers and which are text, what they should look like, etc, which is impossible with CSVs. See http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Thanks. Going to look more into this :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole objective is to do this:

1. Import a master spreadsheet which has confirmation statuses and everything up-to-date
2. Take a new spreadsheet containing vulnerabilities which doesn't have conf status/severity up-to-date.
3. Compare the second spreadsheet to the first. It'll update the severity levels from the second spreadsheet, and then write to a new file.
4. Newly created csv file can be copied and pasted into master spreadsheet. All vulnerabilities which match the first spreadsheet now have the same severity level/confirmation status.

What I'm noticing though, even in Ruby for some reason, is that some of the recommendations in these vulnerabilities have long text; therefore, it's being truncated when the CSV file is created for some reason. Here's a sample piece of the code that I've quickly written for demonstration:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
import getopt, csv

master_vulns = {}
criticality = {}

############################ Extracting unique vulnerabilities from master file
contents = csv.reader(open(argv[1], 'rb'), delimiter=',')

for row in contents:
    if "Confirmation_Status" in row:
        continue
    try:
        if row[7] in master_vulns:
            continue
        if row[7] in master_vulns:
            continue
        master_vulns[row[7]] = row[3]
        criticality[rows[7]] = row[2]
    except Exception:
        pass

############################ Updating confirmation status of newly created file
new_contents = csv.reader(open(argv[1], 'rb'), delimiter=',')
new_data = []
results = open('results.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(results, delimiter=',')

for nrow in new_contents:
    if "Confirmation_Status" in nrow:
        continue
    try:
        if nrow[1] == "DELETE":
            continue
        vuln_name = nrow[7]
        vuln_status = nrow[3]
        criticality = criticality[vuln_name]
        vuln_status = master_vulns[vuln_name]
        nrow[3] = vuln_status
        nrow[2] = criticality
        writer.writerow(nrow)
    except Exception:
        writer.writerow(nrow)
        pass

results.close()
```